# Reading and processing large text file in batches using islice and multiprocessing

Tags: python, windows, iterator, python-multiprocessing, large-files

code doesn't return anything, it keeps running forever. Please help with the code snippet. FYI: I am using `multiprocessing` for the first time.

I have low local memory, hence extracting data from a zip file. My idea is to read n lines at a time using `islice` and process them using `process_logBatch()`.

Running this code on windows machine - Jupyter Notebook.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import zipfile
from itertools import islice
import time
#import pandas as pd  # Unused.

def process_logBatch(next_n_lines):
    l = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(5)]
    print(l)
    return l

def collect_results(result):
    results.extend(result)

pool = mp.Pool(processes=(mp.cpu_count()-1))

results = []

with zipfile.ZipFile('log.zip', 'r') as z:
    with z.open('log.txt') as f:

        while True:
            print(f.closed)
            next_n_lines = [x.decode("utf-8").strip() for x in islice(f, 2)]

            if not next_n_lines:
                break

            try:
                pool.apply_async(process_logBatch, args=(next_n_lines, ), callback=collect_results)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            if counter == 2:
                break
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

print(results)
```

Comment: I see nothing technically wrong — although you're passing a potentially huge argument to the function (so it's not really multiprocessing like you probably want). Could also be a problem with `process_logBatch()`. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @martineau, thanks for the quick reply. I updated the reprodicble code. I already tried with a simple process_logBatch() function that simply returns a list. And for the input, its a zip file with text doc of few text lines.  My intention was to let the multiple cores take care of multiple batch of lines from the text, not sure if thats what I am executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of problems. One is on Windows you need an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement to protect the main module as shown and discussed in the section titled "Safe importing of main module" in the multiprocssing module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods).

However, the second thing isn't so easily solved. Each process runs in its own memory space, so they don't all have the same `results` list. To avoid that I switched to using `Pool.map_async()` and collect the results when all the subprocesses have ended.

Here's a way I think it will work (based on your sample code):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import zipfile
from itertools import islice
import time
#import pandas as pd  # Unused.
import random  # Added.

def process_logBatch(next_n_lines):
    l = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(5)]
    print(l)
    return l

if __name__ == '__main__':

# Not longer needed.
#    def collect_results(result):
#        results.extend(result)

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=(mp.cpu_count()-1))

    with zipfile.ZipFile('log.zip', 'r') as z:
        with z.open('log.txt') as f:

            counter = 0  # Added to avoid NameError because undefined.

            while True:
                next_n_lines = [x.decode("utf-8").strip() for x in islice(f, 2)]

                if not next_n_lines:
                    break

                try:
                    results = pool.map_async(process_logBatch, next_n_lines)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

                if counter == 2:
                    break

            pool.close()
            pool.join()

    print(results.get())
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @martineau. It worked. I created a .py file for the process_logBatch() and imported the file to notebook instead of __main__. I was able to execute your code. FYI, I did upvote the answer, it's just i do not have enough reputations.

Comment: @quantfin_enthusiast: That's good to hear — thanks. Providing a [mcve] really helped. BTW, `import`ing the real `process_logBatch` from another file should be fine.